# How to change all extensions in a folder in batch. (With Directory)

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to make a Batch program that copies all files from a flashdrive onto my desktop, then change all Batch files to Text files. I know of the long way to do this...

```
ren "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch\*.bat" "*.txt"
ren "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch\Format-Transfer\*.bat" "*.txt"
ren "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch\Fun Files\*.bat" "*.txt"
ren "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch\Fun Files\Local ShutDown\*.bat" "*.txt"
...And so on
```

...however, I am asking if there is a way to recursively use a similar command to the one above on every subdirectory.

[I currently have the file movement part solved with the following line.]

```
xcopy /s %dr%:\*.* "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch"
```

Comment: When you copy a file you can `copy` it to a new name, a new extension or both; there's no need to change its name using `ren`ame afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /r %userprofile%\Desktop\Batch %%d in (.) do if exist %%d\*.bat ren %%d\*.bat *.txt
```

Put double quotes around args as needed.

Comment: Your solution does not work, it goes into the first folder, does its job, then fails to continue...?

Comment: Works for me under Windows 7 (I doubt the version of Windows matters).   `for /r` exists to recurse through subfolders, so it should continue.  Perhaps you're having a problem with a space/special-char in a path or filename.  Try using double quotes:
`for /r "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch" %%d in (.) do if exist "%%d\*.bat" ren "%%d\*.bat" "*.txt"`  If still having problems, put an `echo` in front of the `ren` for debug, and see what commands it tries to execute.

Comment: I'm in windows 10...?

Comment: I don't have/use Windows 10, but I can't imagine it wouldn't work there.  Again, insert and `ECHO` to see the commands that are being executed.  IE try this to debug: `for /r "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch" %%d in (.) do ECHO if exist "%%d\*.bat" ren "%%d\*.bat" "*.txt"`  Hopefully that will show the `for /r` command iterating through all your subfolders.

Comment: I found the issue, thanks to you... This recursion adds a "." directory between the last folder, and the actual file names. I can see why, but after tinkering I couldn't fix the bug.

Comment: Yes it does embed a "." and that's expected and intentional.  But that won't change the command  -- the "." in the path has no effect (dot represents the current folder).  So, a rename like `ren  "c:\folder\Desktop\Batch\.\subdir\foo.bat" "*.txt"` will work fine.  If it isn't working I suspect you have some other problem.

Comment: Well if it represents the current folder than in my situation it is actually calling "C:\Users\<me>\Desktop\Batch\Fun files\Fun files\*.bat" as a rename prompt, or am I misunderstanding something

Comment: `.` won't cause the current directory name to be inserted, instead it moves the target relative to the current directory.  So `.\ ` (or `.\.\ `, `.\.\.\ ` etc) in a path has no effect (try `C>dir .\.\.\.\.\*.bat`).  The `for /r "%userprofile%\Desktop\Batch" %%d in (.) do if exist "%%d\*.bat" ren "%%d\*.bat" "*.txt"` will do exactly what you want.  Note if you have existing destination `.txt` files the corresponding .bat files can't be renamed (destination name conflict).  You would have the same problem with your original, one-hardwired-command-per-directory, method.

Comment: I just attempted an implementation again and actually tried to put parenthesis around filepaths and it suddenly works...

Comment: Congrats!  Though I hope you meant to say you put double quotes -- as shown above in my previous comment -- around the filespecs/paths and not parentheses (except where they are required by the `for` command syntax).  I can't imagine parentheses would work.  A parenthesis is actually a valid filename/directory character under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

IF TESTING FROM COMMAND LINE :

```
set source=C:\test\Folder1

for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir "%source%" /b /s /A:-D ^| find ".bat"')  do (
move "%~pa%~na.bat" "%~pa%~na.txt"
)
```

IF TESTING IN BAT FILE

```
set source=C:\test\Folder1

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%source%" /b /s /A:-D ^| find ".bat"')  do (
move "%%~pa%%~na.bat" "%%~pa%%~na.txt"
)
```

Comment: When I tried this in place of the many rename commands it didn't function at all...

Comment: if you tried it straight out of a bat file then you need to change %a to %%a.  Edited code section.  Try for /? in command line as well. That shows you how to use them

Comment: For some reason after using the "batch friendly" code, it gives me a LOT of "file could not be found"